# AWS DescribeExecution for Step Function not returning error/cause

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-step-functions

I have a step function that is failing, and I can see its error and cause in the AWS console, as well as through the cli by calling `aws stepfunctions describe-execution --execution-arn <arn>`.

However, if I create a lambda that invokes StepFunction.DescribeExecution(), the result shows everything except for error and cause.

I can't for the life of me figure out why the StepFunction sdk isn't returning them, my guess is possibly an IAM role issue, but I did give that lambda in question `states:DescribeExecution`.

tldr: Calling DescribeExecution with the aws cli correctly returns the error and cause for a failed step function execution. Calling that same method in another lambda does not.

Comment: It almost certainly won't be a permissions issue. Which SDK and programming language is the Lambda function written with?

Comment: JavaScript/Node.js, using aws-sdk uploaded via serverless

Comment: JavaScript SDK v2 or v3? You might want to test a quick Node.js app using the latest versions of each SDK to see if either/both work.

Comment: @jarmod you were right, it seems to be a bug with v2, it works fine when I switched to the Javascript SDK v3.